# By what rule or property this expression is equal to six?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$2^{-1} \equiv 6\mod{11}$$

Sorry for very strange question. I want to understand on which algorithm there is a computation of this expression. Similarly interested in why this expression is equal to two?

$$6^{-1} \equiv 2\mod11$$

Comment: The algorithm is: Test $2 \cdot 1, 2 \cdot 2, 2 \cdot 3, \dotsc$ until you find $2 \cdot 6=1$...

Answer (score 7):

It's because $2\cdot 6 \equiv 1 \mod 11$

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to understand what $2^{-1}\mod 11$ stands for. Raising to the power $-1$ is usually used to denote the *multiplicative inverse*. That is, $b$ is a multiplicative inverse of $a$ if and only if $a\cdot b=1$. Thus, $2^{-1}\mod 11$ denotes the number such that $$2^{-1}\cdot2\equiv1\mod11$$ Since $2\cdot 6\equiv 12\equiv1\mod11$, we see $2^{-1}\equiv 6\mod11$. We can do the same to show $6^{-1}\equiv 2\mod 11$.

---

For a reliable approach (that is, one that doesn't rely on simply testing $2\cdot 1,2\cdot 2,\cdots,2\cdot 10$ and see which one is $1$), we can use (where we're using that $\gcd(2,11)=1$) $$2^{\phi(11)}\equiv 1\mod 11$$ by [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) (or you could use [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) in this case, since $11$ is prime), and since $\phi(11)=10$, we have \begin{align}
2^{-1}&\equiv 2^{-1}\cdot 1\\
&\equiv 2^{-1}\cdot2^{\phi(11)}\\
&\equiv 2^{-1}\cdot2^{10}\\
&\equiv 2^{-1+10}\\
&\equiv 2^9\\
&\equiv 512\\
&\equiv 6\mod 11
\end{align}

Comment: If you want a really reliable approach, you should take euclidean algorithm...

Comment: This approach is however quite fast and easy to do. The Euclidean Algorithm requires more steps, and is in my opinion more susceptible to making calculation mistakes. Both methods are fine though, perhaps this is more a matter of preference. Note that I didn't state in my answer that it is *the* reliable method but it's *a* reliable method.

Comment: Euclidean algorithm is way faster for large numbers. Thats why computers use euclidean algorithm. Working with small numbers, my "trial and error approach" is even faster and easier to do than your approach. You started to call my method unreliable, not me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have $2\times 6=12$ which is $1$ mod $11$. Hence, we see that that $2\times 6=1$ mod $11$.

Now the set of congruence numbers modulo $11$ (often noted $\mathbb{Z}/11$) is a ring with addition and multiplication coming from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Saying that $6^{-1}\text{  mod }11=2$ is saying that $6$ mod $11$ is invertible as an element of the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/11,+,\times)$ and that its inverse is $2$ mod $11$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $2^{-1} \pmod{11}$ means the *multiplicative inverse* of $2$ modulo $11$, that is, a number $x$ satisfying the equation $2x \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$.

Since $2 \cdot 6 \equiv 12 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, $2^{-1} \equiv 6 \pmod{11}$.  The same calculation shows that $6^{-1} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$.

The multiplicative inverse of $6$ exists modulo $11$ since $\gcd(6, 11) = 1$.

We can find the multiplicative inverse of $6$ modulo $11$ using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
\begin{align*}
11 & = 1 \cdot 6 + 5\\
6 & = 1 \cdot 5 + 1\\
5 & = 5 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
We solve for $1$ as a linear combination of $6$ and $11$.
\begin{align*}
1 & = 6 - 5\\
  & = 6 - (11 - 6)\\
  & = 2 \cdot 6 - 11
\end{align*}
Hence, $2 \cdot 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \iff 6^{-1} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$.

Let's see what happens when we use the extended Euclidean algorithm to solve for $2^{-1}$ modulo $11$.

The multiplicative inverse of $2$ exists modulo $11$ since $\gcd(2, 11) = 1$.
\begin{align*}
11 & = 5 \cdot 2 + 1\\
2 & = 2 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Solving for $1$ as a linear combination of $2$ and $11$ yields
$$1 = 11 - 5 \cdot 2$$
Thus, $$-5 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \iff 2^{-1} \equiv -5 \pmod{11}$$
What does this mean?  It means that for each $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, 
$$2(-5 + 11t) \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$
In particular, if $t = 1$, we obtain 
$$2 \cdot 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \iff 2^{-1} \equiv  6 \pmod{11}$$
Why is $2(-5 + 11t) \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ for $t \in \mathbb{Z}$?  Observe that 
$$2(-5 + 11t) \equiv -10 + 22t \equiv 1 - 11 + 22t \equiv 1 + 11(2t - 1) \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$

Answer (score -1):

It is part of the collection of integer pairs such that:

$$xy\equiv1\mod p$$

in this case with $p=11$.

For $p=11$, they are $1\cdot1,2\cdot6,3\cdot4,5\cdot9,7\cdot8$ and $10\cdot10$

Except for $1$ and $p-1$, each $x$ is paired to a unique $y$.